# JSON-data from iOS into PHP-script

Tags: php, iphone, ios, json

How can I access json data within a php-script, which it received via http-post?
I'm doing the following on the iOS-side:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:NULL];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/script.php"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:data];

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

How do I access this data in the php-script? In other words, when I call `json_decode(...)` in the php-script, what is `...`?

Comment: A good way to debug this kind of stuff is to `var_dump($_POST)` to a log file and see what you're getting sent.

Comment: I'd suggest finding a basic PHP course first of all to make sure you understand the basics (getting the POST data is fairly basic) of PHP.

Comment: Sorry, but $_POST doesn't contain any data, when posting json-data directly. And accessing 'php://input' doesn't seem so basic to me.

Comment: Woah - what's with all the down-votes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your are sending your JSON in POST method , It can be received in PHP with the below code

```
<?php $handle = fopen('php://input','r');
                $jsonInput = fgets($handle);
                // Decoding JSON into an Array
                $decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
?>
```

Comment: @nakkeeran, can we always use php://input??? never used it before but it seems to work on my local setup

Answer (score 1):

The post request when sent using iOS does not works with $_POST. If similar request is issued using js the json in post does works.

Comment: The correct way of doing it would be to set the header to text/html. If you set the header to application/json the php script just mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

In the php script you take the POST data and do

```
json_decode($data);
```

and that will give you an object you can work with.

Comment: I think. Give it a shot, and let me know

Comment: No, I doesn't work with $_POST. By the way, why does this question get so many down-votes?! What's so bad about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
    [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

This code can be used to send a response