# Web services on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, json, web-services

I am new to iPhone. I want to  know about web service, my requirement is I have to store the sign up details in to server. I have my php script in the server. How to store those details and get those details in another `view`. I would like to use JSON web service.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: can you please write your URL here!

Answer (score 1):

i think you want JsonKit please [use this link](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) , it's support both ios4 and Ios 5

How to Implement json in your project (means Example) [use this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) , this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

you may use [ASIHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for server calls.

Answer (score 1):

After entering Signup details and pressing the Signup button, you can send a HTTP POST request to your PHP server with the signup details encrypted as HTTP parameters and then save those to the database.
And then when you move to the next view and want to get the signup details :-

**1.** If you do not want to save them on the ios app, use Keychain to store them locally. [Check here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html) for detailed implementation of how to store
**2.** If you want them to save to the server and then get them on another view using HTTP request, send a HTTP request and get the encrypted (for security) JSON and then parse it using [SBJson framework.](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i post my signup details in to my php server

Comment: Check this once -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576741/json-data-from-ios-into-php-script