# How to use JSONKit to transmit data to a server in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nskeyedarchiver, data-transfer-objects, jsonkit

I'm basically trying to send data to a server that contains objects and fellow peers have told me to use JSONKit.

As of now, I've implemented *NSCoding* protocol and serialized my objects with *NSKeyedArchiver*. But I can't find any resources on how to send out the data.

My code:
import

JSONKit.h

```
Art* art = [[Art alloc] initWithArt:@"test"]; // Object that implemented NSCoding
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:art];
```

This is where the confusion begins.

```
JSONDecoder *jsonDecoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] init];
[jsonDecoder objectWithData:data error:&err];
```

I need to now send the data to the server with this:

```
[server sendData:finalData error:&err];
```

but I do not know how to get that *finalData*.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### [You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming) [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323709/send-image-to-server-as-binary-data) [figure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [out](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [how](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) [to](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/parsing-json-on-ios-with-asihttprequest-and-sbjson/) [send](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883081/post-data-in-objective-c-using-json) [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request) [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576741/json-data-from-ios-into-php-script)????